# "Увидеть трое незнакомых людей" — так разве правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, числительные

Вот цитата с [портала Екатеринбурга](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/63803-kak-pravilno-s-pyatyu-lyudmi-ili-chelovekami/):

> Таким образом, правильно: встретиться с пятью человеками, увидеть **трое** незнакомых людей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, последней строкой этого материала, начинающейся словами "таким образом", *небрежно* (возможно даже, редактором веб-страницы) подытожен предыдущий абзац, в конце которого приводилось сочетание "*трёх* взрослых людей", - ведь перед этим, при всём множестве примеров с числительными, нигде не употреблялась их *собирательная* форма (трое, четверо, пятеро или шестеро).

Comment: Наверное. Спасибо! Написал им письмо.

Comment: Значит, "увидеть троих незнакомых людей" неправильно? Только трёх? А без "незнакомых" правильно "увидеть трёх человек", да, а не как у Игоря?

Comment: "Троих незнакомых людей увидеть" можно (как и просто _троих людей_), но это за пределыми их темы: на предмет выбора между **человек** и **людей** рассматривались только обычные количественные числительные. Но не всё у них гладко, сомнение вызывает (при любом прилагательном) вариант "незнакомых человек" наряду с "незнакомых людей" - кто такие "незнакомые человеки"? Вставка прилагательного затрудняет его согласование с примыкающими словами; возможно, лучше изменить порядок слов: _пять человек незнакомцев_, поскольку "человек" в таких сочетаниях - единица измерения.

Comment: Спасибо! А с портала мне так ничего и не ответили. :) Всё-таки хочется до конца разобраться в оттенках смысла "увидеть трёх/троих людей". А также понять, что меняется, когда мы меняем в этой фразе без прилагательного "человек" на "людей".

Comment: _Н. Киреева. Грамматический метод обучения русскому правописанию. Книга 1: лекции по орфографии_ Здесь есть подробные рекомендации; видимо, отсюда повторено "пять незнакомых человек" (а если "хороших человек"?):

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=LuhNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT558&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=MsXpAPWgfU&sig=ACfU3U3PtIaomYo8cWQNENdM_2OY7aqqPg&w=1280

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=LuhNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT558&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=MsXpAPWgfU&sig=ACfU3U3PtIaomYo8cWQNENdM_2OY7aqqPg&w=1280 Кстати, здесь критикуется _троих людей_ без прилагательного (мол, практически не употребляется).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр!

Answer (score 5):

Авторы портала не до конца разобрались в правилах: числительное "трое" склоняется по-разному с неодушевленными и одушевленными существительными.
В орфографическом словаре они отдельно упомянуты как *трое-1* и *трое-2* ([**трое**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5)).

С неодушевленными существительными форма винительного падежа "трое", а с одушевленными — "троих":
*увидеть **трое саней***, но *увидеть **троих людей***.